# How to access buffer contents of Expect module in perl

Tags: perl, expect

I am using expect to automate terminal based applications. I will send data depending on result from "expect" command. I knew that expect, while doing a string matching stores all the unmatched string patterns in a buffer. For example $expect_out(0,string) is used to store the string that expect is actually waiting for, while $expect_out(buffer) contains all the unmatched string patterns occurred till the previous command.

I want to know if there is any way of accessing these expect buffers, like copying expect buffer contents into some variable as shown below

```
$mybuffer = $expect_out(buffer);
```

but the above statement is actually throwing an error "syntax error at perl_app_hh.pl line 72, near "$expect_out(""

I just want to copy contents of expect buffer to a variable. So please help me on this issue.

Comment: All the above stuff should work using the expect module for perl from cpan.

Comment: `$expect_out(0,string)` and `$expect_out(buffer)` are not valid perl syntax.  Can you show us your existing code that you want to modify?

Comment: print ("\n\n\n ******About to print expect buffer contents...************\n\n\n\n");
#$mybuffer = $expect_out(buffer);
print ("\n The expect buffer contents are ", $buffer, "\n");
print "$expect_out(0,string)";

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to read [the documentation for the Expect module](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod). `$expect(buffer)` is not valid Perl.

```
$exp = Expect->spawn(...);
$exp->send(...);
$buffer = $exp->before();
```